# Webpack and Babel not parsing es2015 correctly

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to parse a couple of files with es6 syntax into es5 with babel and webpack, but it seems that the transpilation is not being done. The code is from webpack docs.

These are the files and my configuration:

## app.js (entry point)

```
'use strict';

import 'babel-polyfill';
import cats from './cats';
import $ from 'jquery';

$('<h1>Cats</h1>').appendTo('body');
const ul = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo('body');
for (const cat of cats) {
    $('<li></li>').text(cat).appendTo(ul);
}
```

## cats.js

```
var cats = ['dave', 'henry', 'martha'];
module.exports = cats;
```

## .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }]
    }
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-doc-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "regenerate": "^1.3.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.9.5"
  }
}
```

When I execute webpack, it doesnt transpile the code, it just copies the result.

This is the result:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports,     __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    'use strict';

    import 'babel-polyfill';
    import cats from './cats';
    import $ from 'jquery';

    $('<h1>Cats</h1>').appendTo('body');
    const ul = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo('body');
    for (const cat of cats) {
        $('<li></li>').text(cat).appendTo(ul);
    }

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Also if I run:

```
babel --presets es2015 src/app.js --out-file bin/app.bundle2.js
```

from the command line with babel-cli the result is not fine, cause it still has requires, that the browser cant work with. This is the result:

```
'use strict';

require('babel-polyfill');

var _cats = require('./cats');

var _cats2 = _interopRequireDefault(_cats);

var _jquery = require('jquery');

var _jquery2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jquery);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {     default: obj }; }

(0, _jquery2.default)('<h1>Cats</h1>').appendTo('body');
var ul = (0, _jquery2.default)('<ul></ul>').appendTo('body');
var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
    for (var _iterator = _cats2.default[Symbol.iterator](), _step;     !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done);     _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        var cat = _step.value;

        (0, _jquery2.default)('<li></li>').text(cat).appendTo(ul);
    }
} catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
    try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
            _iterator.return();
        }
    } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError) {
            throw _iteratorError;
        }
    }
}
```

I have read and tried almost everything that I have found all around googling.

I tried the following things:

I added more presets (stage-0, stage-1, react)
I tried including just code inside src folder (my files are inside this folder)

I added the es2015 preset in the webpack config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }],
        query: {
            presets: [
                require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015')
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

, and i got 'Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory' so I added the es2015 preset in the webpack config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }],
        query: {
            presets: [
                require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015')
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

, and i got 'ERROR in ./~/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js'. This was a dead end, I tried adding the npm modules

```
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
"regenerate": "^1.3.1",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.9.5"
```

but I couldnt solve it, so I had to came back to the config I put at the begining and trust in babelrc config.

I dont know what else can I do.

Thanks in advance any help.